# Responsive image tinymce image link

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm expanding an existing website. I have the site published (if you want to take a look [click here](http://www.coblabergajove.cat)). I have just added a very simple blog (made with php and mysql) and it works well, except for one thing. If I add an image to a new or post, the person that is writing the post is able resize it. The problem is that the image has static width and height, and then if I access the blog on a mobile device, the image is cut because it's bigger than the width of the device. I don't know how to solve it, I thaunght I could modify the plugin that allows to insert images to add this parameters (which makes an image responsive):

```
max-width="['user selected width'], width=100%, height=auto
```

I've been trying to modify the plugin but i find it very hard to understand, and i'm not very experienced on javascript. [Here's the plugin.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2720540/plugin.min.js) I'm using tinymce editor to edit or add posts.
Anyone knows were I have to add this parameters? Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

on tinymceini put this.... and voala

```
image_dimensions: false,
         image_class_list: [
            {title: 'Responsive', value: 'img-responsive'}
        ]
```

Comment: where do I need to place this in yii2?

Comment: you place this in the mce initialiasation :  tinymce.init({ ...      for bootstrap 4 : img-fluid instead of img-responsive

Comment: Does nothing on TinyMCE version 5.

Comment: Works great on TinyMCE 6 for Angular. Here's more info: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#image_class_list

Answer (score 11):

add this class in file content.min.css

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: The pure CSS solution that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 7):

No need to handle this via separate te css. You can apply "img-responsive" class at the time of adding the image in tinymce editor itself.

Add below property in your tintmce editor properties:

```
image_class_list: [
    {title: 'Responsive', value: 'img-responsive'}
],
```

Reference and credits:
http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=114620#p114620

Comment: I did not check that somebody has already posted this solution above.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found, instead of modifying the html code that produces tinymce to insert an image, I modify the image proportions on the css stylesheet by modifying the img. I use this code:

```
[element that contains the image] img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I found using css and jquery instead of tinymce plugins.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tiny_images = $(this).find('img').map(function(){

        if($(this).attr('class') == undefined){
    
            if($(this).attr('src').indexOf("data:image")!=-1){
                $(this).addClass("tiny-img");
            }
            
        }

    }).get()

});
```

```css
 .tiny-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS is a safer way to do this

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With version 5 you want to put the same code at the end of the /skins/ui/oxide and /skins/ui/oxide-dark content.css files.

```
/* <your name> added the following to create responsive images */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```